# How do you make eclipse use an existing svn working copy?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I've got a working copy checked out with svn; furthermore, I've created a new project in Eclipse that has the root of the working copy as the project's location. I want to be able to do stuff like compare versions from Eclipse. I have Subclipse 1.4.8, but that doesn't seem to give me what I want. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 22):

i have an svn working copy that also is a project in eclipse. after installing the subclipse plugin i had the same problem, the working copy was not recognized as such.

i just managed by chance to get it recognized as an svn working copy by renaming the project in question and then renaming it back to its old name. not very nice, but it did the trick :-)

Comment: Tip:  Press F2 to open the rename dialog when on a project.  It's amazing that renaming worked.

Comment: Still an issue 5 years later

Comment: Rename must be done within Eclipse. Select the project and then press F2 or select File > Rename... I kept the defaults and it seems to have worked with Eclipse Mars.

Answer (score 8):

There is an option when creating a new project, to use an existing source directory:

New project/ new Java Project / Create project from existing source.

Use that, tell it where your source lives, and it should automatically detect if it's a SVN working copy.

Comment: I am create a proj from an existing dir, but it's not detecting it as an svn working copy :/

Comment: Strange, just tried it, works for me. I also use Subclipse 1.4. Does Subclipse work at all? Try checking out a small project as a test. Also check if your working copy really is a proper SVN working copy.

Comment: Yes, subclipse works; I was able to check out some code using it.

Comment: I'm kind of thinking there's a version conflict between the client implemented by subclipse and Tortoise; I have a pretty recent version of Tortoise, so I'm guessing it's using version 1.5 or something.

Comment: That would be an explanation. Every WC directory has a folder .svn. .svn/format contains the version of the WC; check if it matches between your WC and one checked out using Subclipse.

Comment: I just wanted to drop a note to make sure you're using the correct version of Subclipse based on the installed version of Subversion. 

If you're already using TortoiseSVN, right-click on your repository folder > TortoiseSVN > About: Subversion {version number}

If you have a particularly large repo, then Eclipse might spin for a while as it indexes the local files. If you get the message "the user operation is waiting for background . . . ", then just sit it out or force Eclipse to quit and restart it.

Answer (score 4):

I guess this is not possible with Subclipse as it's given in its [documentation](http://svn.collab.net/subclipse/help/topic/org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.doc/html/advanced/wc-outside-workspace.html) that, you can only import an existing svn-managed folder under one condition, according to the doc:

> "The only requirement is that your
> working copy has to also be a valid
> Eclipse project."

So, if you have a working copy that is not a complete eclipse project, Subclipse will not connect it to SVN.

Comment: Your avatar totally helped you get my up vote. This just leads to the question "What's a 'valid' Eclipse project?". I think I have one of those, because I have a .project file in the root of my working copy.

Answer (score 4):

You can right click on the root node of your project and select: Team / Share project

Then you choose SVN, let the default settings and it should work fine!

Answer (score 3):

I am answering this after a long time of the question being asked. I ended up here because I was facing the same problem.

My solution was to create an empty .svn folder at the root folder of the project (in the latest version of svn client tortoise all meta-data is at the root folder). Then did an eclipse refresh and voila it did the trick. I am running subclipse core - 1.8.4.

Comment: "Share Project..." was disabled until I did this.  Then I clicked on Shared Project, selected SVN, and it saw that it was already checked out.  Good Stuff.  Mars 4.5.0, Subclipse 1.10.3

Answer (score 2):

One step that seemed to work for me, that no one has explicitly mentioned yet: I closed and then re-opened the project. I tried the "rename" trick, above, and that didn't work, but perhaps the poster of that answer also closed the project - they didn't detail exactly what steps they went thru to rename it. (I found you *don't* have to close the project to rename it, but perhaps they did.)

< /rob>

Comment: This works for me too - just closing and re-opening a project I'd imported as an existing maven project.

Comment: close -> reopen -> rename -> rename back. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I couldn't use an existing copy because I checked out the code using a newer version of Subversion on the command-line and Subclipse 1.4 couldn't recognize it.  Upgrading and going through the improved "Share Project" menu resolved the problem.

I got this tip from the forums here:

http://subclipse.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=1047&dsMessageId=2380064

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and here are the details of the fix.

My Eclipse is "Helios Service Release 1".

I had an SVN checkout on my filesystem, I went to `New Java Project`, unchecked `Use default location`, chose the location, went to next step, chose the source folder and said `Finish`.

The project came up with no disk icon on it. As per few forum posts, right-clicked on the project, went to `Team` > `Share Project`, chose `SVN`, clicked `Next`, and the option was only to share the files to the SVN Repository for the first time.

I said `Cancel`, and the option is to make changes to the SVN plug-in settings. Went to `Window` menu, chose `Preferences`, browsed `Team`> `SVN`. Chose the `SVN Connector` tab, changed the `SVNKit 1.2.3` to `SVNKit 1.3.5` and said `OK`.

Then, right clicked on the project, said `Team`> `SVN`, on the next screen, chose the option `Use Project Settings` and clicked `Finish`. The disk button came to the project and the SVN URL got displayed on it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the repository to your list of repositories in subclipse by choosing Window->Show View->Other... and choose SVN->SVN Repositories. Put in all the necessary info to connect to the repository.

Next, right click the repository and choose "checkout". If the project doesn't already have an eclipse .project file, you can create a new project from the source. If it already has a .project file, it will import that .project and use that as your eclipse project locally.

Comment: I want eclipse to use an _existing_ working copy. Your suggestions, which probably works, involves checking out another copy.

Comment: I've always found that if you don't create a project in eclipse by checking out a project in subclipse, it's very difficult to create a project from that code, which is why I suggested the whole "starting from scratch" idea.

Answer (score 0):

It will definitively not work if you use a different version of svn to checkout, that the one that is supported by Eclipse.  I had this problem as I used svn 1.6 to checkout but I had an older eclipse version that had only 1.5.  Subclipse has its own build-in svn client (Actually, in two flavors if I am not mistaken).

Check that the subclipse version matches the svn client that you used to checkout.  You can check the plugin version number for subclipse (Help -> About -> Click on subversion logo) and match it against svn --version

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
1) Go to the 'SVN Repository Exploring' perspective and add a folder somewhere above your working copy
2) Close and open the Eclipse projects.

This should then be enough to get them recognized by Subclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar situation were existing projects would not get associated with the Subversive plugin. Unfortunately, none of the previous suggestions helped (renaming projects etc.). What has helped is removing projects from Eclipse by deleting them -- just the projects from Package Explorer and not the actual directories and files on disc (the deletion prompt has a special checkbox for that, which is unchecked by default) -- and reimporting the deleted projects as existing projects back.

Of course, as mentioned in some of the answers here, the relevant SVN repositories need to be registered with Eclipse before reimporting the projects. Otherwise, there would no repositories to re-associate the projects with.

Comment: In my case, I additionally needed to make sure that the .project file is added to the working copy.

Answer (score 0):

When you open a versioned project (i.e., a project in SVN working copy) in Eclipse, that was never previously used with Subclipse, you need to perform these steps:

1. Right-click the project in **Project Explorer**.
2. **Select Team | Share Project**.
3. At this point Subclipse will tell you that "The project is already configured with SVN repository information". Click **Next**.

Subclipse automatically recognizes this project as versioned and all the features of the SVN plug-in should become available.