# The best Eclipse SVN client or Subversive -> Subclipse migration

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, subversive

As you possibly know, the [Subversive](https://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) project is dead (and even doesn't work with Eclipse 2021-09; everything is installing w/o errors but has an issue with missed resources during the startup).

I have a bunch of legacies SVN-based projects and I indeed need that svn client (and preferably in the Eclipse). AFAIK the only option that I've for now is [Subclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/subclipse). Please guide me if I'm wrong and exists better SVN clients.

So actually I've 3 questions here:

1. Can I somehow keep the Subversive client and upgrade to the latest
   version of Eclipse (e.g. 2021-09)?
2. If the answer to the previous question is "NO" (and I feel that it is), what is the best SVN client for the Eclipse for now?
3. I suppose that the answer to  the previous question would be "Subclipse". In that case, do I have an option to upgrade (including uncommitted files!) from Subversive to Subclipse.

**Regrading the latest part (Upgrade from Subversive -> Subclipse).**

Usually, similar tasks are done as "Team, Share project" but that option was missed in my eclipse workspaces. I mean in the workspace I've 2 projects: the old one is Subversive based where in the Team submenu I've only "Apply patch" option and a new one checked out via Subclipse and "disconnected" that can be reconnected again as I mentioned earlier ("Team, Share project").

I even "svn upgrade" both projects with client 1.14.1, but the result it the same: I can reconnect the Subclipse project and can't do that for Subversive.

Any thoughts and answers are welcome!

**Update #1**

Unfortunately, Team popup menu doesn't have an option "Share project"
[image]

**Update #2**

Here is the solution [subclipse not showing "share project" option on project context menu in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767144/subclipse-not-showing-share-project-option-on-project-context-menu-in-eclipse)

Comment: Most have moved on to Git, but Subversive is not yet archived (which would mean dead). Or are you saying that you contributed a patch that was not accepted?

Comment: @howlger Not sure that I got your answer. I need SVN. I can't move to Git in some projects (many reasons). The question is how to survive in Eclipse existed project with SVN. The Subversive plugin doesn't work anymore in latest versions of Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there should be no problems switching from Subversive to Subclipse. In previous versions it [was even possible to use them side-by-side in a single workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9228741/761095).

1. Most likely, you don't need to `svn upgrade` your working copies. Subversive uses SVN 1.9, and Subclipse uses Subversion 1.14. There were no working copy format changes in these versions. You only need to run `svn upgrade` if a working copy was created with Subversion 1.6 or an older client version.
2. I think that if you uninstall Subversive and install Subclipse, it will work out of the box. The UI may be slightly different, though.
3. Team | Share project is used to add an existing non-versioned project to Subversion or another version control system. I've just tested it with the most recent Eclipse and Subclipse versions, and it works.

If you have some specific problems that need to be addressed, you should ask questions about them in separate posts on SO and provide information for further troubleshooting (screenshots, error messages, a reproduction script). Right now, your question is too vague.

**Update #1**

If a project is already versioned and you have a working copy with in on your computer, open the project in Project Explorer and select Team | Share Project. Select SVN and click Next. Subclipse automatically recognizes this project as versioned and you will see the following window. Click Finish and from now on all Subclipse features should work with it.

[image]

Comment: I did. After that (uninstall Subversive and install Subclipse) all my projects are unlinked from SVN and I don't have an option to relink them (usually, Team->Share). The only option that I see in such scenario it to create new workspace (or delete/check out) existed projects using Subclipse. But my goal is to make that migration as simple as possible. Any ideas?

Comment: @FoxyBOA I've just updated the answer. The option Team | Share Project should be present when you right-click your project in Project Explorer. Maybe this will help, too https://stackoverflow.com/q/1156330/761095

Comment: @FoxyBOA try to reinstall Subclipse. I'm not sure why the option is missing.

Comment: Updated question (see Update #1). I know about that option and it missed. Install the latest version :)

Comment: I tried many recipes - no luck. I can even create 2 projects (check out Subclipse and Subversive). The first one allows to "relink" the project. The second one - nope. Both of them looks identical from SVN point of view.